# A* Pathfinding problems Processing(Java)

Tags: java, processing, a-star

I'm quite new to programming though following a bunch of tutorials I've ended up with this code to deal with the pathfinding of a small game I'm trying to make.

If works for small and straight paths but not for complex routes (it freezes and `closedSet.size()` gets larger than 70000 in a grid that is only 54 * 46).

Note that `wall` is true depending on the height of the colliding tiles, so it may be true coming from a point but false coming from another. Is that the problem?

```
import java.util.*;

int heuristic(int x,int y,int x_,int y_){
  int dstX = abs(x - x_);
  int dstY = abs(y - y_);
  if(dstX > dstY){
    return 14*dstY + 10*(dstX - dstY);
  }else{
    return 14*dstX + 10*(dstY - dstX);
  }
}

boolean wall(int x, int y, int x_, int y_){
  Tile tileS = getTile(x, y);
  Tile tileCurr = getTile(x_, y_);
  if(abs(tileS.altitude - tileCurr.altitude) > 1 || tileS.altitude  < 1){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}

ArrayList<PVector> findPath(int startx, int starty, int endx, int endy){
  
  Queue<Spot> openSet = new PriorityQueue<Spot>(fComparator);
  ArrayList<Spot> closedSet = new ArrayList<Spot>();
  
  Spot start = new Spot(startx, starty);
  Spot end = new Spot(endx, endy);
  Spot current = start;
  
  openSet.add(start);
  
  while(!openSet.isEmpty()){
    
    current = openSet.poll();
    closedSet.add(current);
    
    println(closedSet.size());
    
    if (current.x == end.x && current.y == end.y) {
      break;
    }
    
    ArrayList<Spot> successors = new ArrayList<Spot>();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < collidingTiles.size(); i++){
      JSONObject difference = collidingTiles.getJSONObject(i);
      /*JSONArray such as
      [{x: -1, y: -1},{x: 0, y: -1},...](not including {x:0, y:0})
     */

      int x_ = difference.getInt("x");
      int y_ = difference.getInt("y");
      int x = x_ + current.x;
      int y = y_ + current.y;
      
      if(x >= 0 && x <= map.columns && y >= 0 && y <= map.rows){
        Spot s = new Spot(x, y);
        successors.add(s);
      }
    }
    
    for(Spot s: successors){
      if (!closedSet.contains(s) && !wall(s.x, s.y, current.x, current.y)) {
        int tempG = current.g  + heuristic(s.x, s.y, current.x, current.y);
        
        if(tempG < s.g || !openSet.contains(s)){
          s.g = tempG;
          s.h = heuristic(s.x, s.y, end.x, end.y);
          s.f = s.g + s.h;
          s.parent = current;
          if (!openSet.contains(s)) {
            openSet.add(s);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    successors.clear();
  }
  
  ArrayList<PVector> path = new ArrayList<PVector>();
  Spot temp = current;
  PVector tile = new PVector(temp.x + 0.5, temp.y + 0.5);
  path.add(tile);
  while (temp.parent != null) {
    tile = new PVector(temp.parent.x + 0.5, temp.parent.y + 0.5);
    path.add(0, tile);
    temp = temp.parent;
  }
  return path;
}

class Spot{
  int x, y;
  int f, g, h = 0;
  Spot parent;
  
  Spot(int x_, int y_){
    x = x_;
    y = y_;
  }
  
}

Comparator<Spot> fComparator = new Comparator<Spot>() {
  @Override
  int compare(Spot s1, Spot s2) {
    return s1.f - s2.f;
  }
};
```

Any recommendations or minor changes are also appreciated.

Comment: I see a lot of integer numbers where I should see map coordinates, are these really coordinates or are they another way you use to calculate distance based on a model? As a rule of thumb you should use float or a similar format to store map coordinates, especially if you're going to calculate stuff based on these.

Comment: Your post is well written, but as it's mostly debugging, you would raise your chances of having help _a lot_ with a [minimal, reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Of course it's not always possible, but at least being able to run it would let more people in a better position to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `closedSet.size()` gets larger than 70000 in a grid that is only 54 * 46

Your code does implement some logic that says

0. "if a node is closed, don't process it again", and
1. "if the node is already in the open set, compare G scores"

But in both cases it does not work, because `Spot` does not implement `equals`, and therefore `contains` is comparing for reference equality and it will always be false. So, implement `Spot.equals`. Specifically, make it compare only `x` and `y`, because `f/g/h/parent` are allowed to be different for nodes that are considered equal for this purpose.

Even when it works, using `contains` on an `ArrayList` and a `PriorityQueue` is not so good for performance. For the closed list, it is easy to use a `HashSet` (of course, also implement `Spot.hashCode`, in some way that depends only on `x` and `y`). For the open list, getting rid of slow `contains` is more work. One trick you can use is manually maintaining a binary heap, and additionally have a `HashMap` which maps an `x,y` pair to the index in the heap where the corresponding node is located. The reason for manually maintaining a heap is that the `HashMap` must be updated whenever nodes are moved in the queue, and the normal `PriorityQueue` does not have such functionality.

The way that finding successors works also worries me from a performance perspective, but I cannot see the details.

> Note that `wall` is true depending on the height of the colliding tiles, so it may be true coming from a point but false coming from another. Is that the problem?

That's fine, A* can tolerate a spot being reachable from one side but not an other. What it cannot natively take into account is if the direction a spot was reached from affects which successors that node has, but that does not happen here.